# Gravar a Session/Cookie do usuário ao fazer login

Tags: c#, mvc, cookies, asp.net-core

Em aplicações WEB normalmente na tela de Login tem a opção **Lembre-me**, nesta aplicação salvará os dados do usuário uma vez que o mesmo deixe *marcado* a opção.

Assim quando o usuário entrar novamente no site, ao invés de ir para tela de Login, irá direto para a tela inicial da aplicação, não sendo necessário logar novamente.

Lendo alguns forúns vi algo relacionado com **Cookies** e **Session** do usuário. Porém não ficou claro para mim como é feito esse processo.

> 1 - Pegar a *Session* do usuário significa o que?
>
> 2 - A implementação dos *Cookies* significa o que?
>
> 3 - Os 2 casos se interam para validar/gravar o acesso do usuário, não
>   precisando de realizar um novo acesso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Session significa você armazenar dados durante a atividade do usuário no teu site, e expirará quando ele sair ou após um determinado tempo de inatividade. Essa informação esta disponível em qualquer lugar da aplicação no backend.

No caso do ASP.Net MVC com IIS, o modo mais comum de Session é InProc que faz com que esses dados sejam armazenados na memória do servidor.

No ASP.NET Core, a session é criada utilizando cookies, para manter essas informações.

2 - Cookies são informações armazenadas no browser, onde podem ser acessadas tanto no backend quanto no frontend, dependendo da configuração. Essas informações são trafegadas em todas as requisições devido ao HTTP ser um protocolo que não mantém estado e também possuem data de expiração.

3 - No teu caso, para manter o usuário logado, a melhor opção é utilizar cookies. Você poderá criar um cookie, identificando o usuário, determinando a validade e na próxima vez que ele acessar o teu site pelo mesmo browser, você identificar a existência desse cookie e realiza os tratamentos necessários para autenticar novamente o usuário.

Como sugestão, você pode dar uma olhada aqui, que fala mais a respeito de 
[autenticação com cookies](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x#persistent-cookies)